# Finding the matrix exponantial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to calculate the following:

$e^{xA} ,  A= 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I use the following rule:

$e^{xA} = \sum \frac{x^k}{k!}A^k$

Now I'm looking for a matrix such that:
$A=S D S^{-1}$.

So I calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A, these are:

$\lambda _0=3 , \lambda_{1,2} = 0 $

$\vec{y_0} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} $,$\vec{y_1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $,$\vec{y_2} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$

So I have the following 3 matrices:

$ 
S = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&-1&0\\
1&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
, D = \begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix} , S^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

But when I calculate $SDS^{-1}$ I don't get A.

Can someone help me where I have gone wrong. I thought I understood it up until this point, but there must be something wrong with my reasoning because I have checked every thing with mathematica.

I also don't know what to do when I have found the correct S and D.

Comment: Your $D$ is wrong, the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: You've made a mistake, your matrix should be similar to a diagonal matrix; you get a Jordan block $3I_1$, and also $O_2$ (2 by 2 zero matrix).

Comment: You have no accepted answers. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Can you explain to me how I should find the correct D then? Because I thought that you just put the eigenvalues on the diagonal and if the multiplicity is higher then 1 you put a 1 above the corresponding eigenvalue. And what do you mean with "you have no accepted answers"?

Comment: When you have a basis of eigenvectors, then the matrix is necessarily diagonal. As for 'no accepted answers', when someone answers your question and you are satisfied with their answer, it's good etiquette to click the tick underneath the up/down vote arrows on their answer. Read the links @GitGud posted.

Comment: @ah11950 I know that I can diagonalize my matrix, but I can't figure out how to do this. Could you please help me

Comment: robjohn has explained below. If you want to find the JCF, just multiply $S^{-1}AS$ (you've calculated $S$ correctly, as in this case it is just the matrix with the eigenvectors as its columns).

Comment: Your initial matrix $A$ obviously has rank $1$, but your $D$ has rank $2$; that should be a red flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for $n\gt0$, $A^n=3^{n-1}A$ This should be enough to compute $e^{xA}$.

---

You have the wrong Jordan Normal Form for $A$. [Since $A$ is Hermitian, it is diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Properties):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&-1&0\\
1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&-1&0\\
1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: If I use this I find the following: $e^{xA}=e^{3x}A$. But if I use the function MatrixExp in mathematica I find a totally different solution.

Comment: @user118436: check the computation of $e^{xA}$. Remember that $A^0\ne3^0A$.

Comment: I thought that the Jordan Normal Form has a 1 above one of the eigenvalues if this eigenvalue has a multiplicty higher then 1. Is this incorrect or is this a special case?

Comment: @user118436: that is incorrect. In cases where there is a basis of eigenvectors, the matrix is diagonalizable. The number of diagonal blocks with size at least $k$ is the nullity of $(A-I\lambda)^k$ minus the nullity of $(A-I\lambda)^{k-1}$. In this case, the nullity of $A$ is $2$ so there are $2$ blocks of size $1$ for the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by blocks and their size? I have never really learned anything about Jordan Normal Forms. On the internet I try to learn more about it, but I can't find a website that teaches me properly.

Comment: @user118436: $\boxed{\begin{matrix}\lambda\end{matrix}}$ is a block of size $1$. $\boxed{\begin{matrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{matrix}}$ is a block of size $2$. $\boxed{\begin{matrix}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&1\\0&0&\lambda\end{matrix}}$ is a block of size $3$. etc.

Comment: I'm now using your first hint (for$n>0,A^n=3^nA$). I use the following reasoning, but there must be something wrong as I get the wrong answer: $\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}A^k=A^0+\sum_{k=1}^\inf \frac{x^k}{k!} A^k=I+(1+ (\sum_{k=1}^\inf \frac{x^k}{k!} 3^k) - 1)A = I +(e^{3x}-1)A$.

Comment: @user118436: I fixed a typo in the hint. Try again.

Comment: Thank you, I finally have the correct answer :) $\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}A^k=A^0+\sum_{k=1}^\inf \frac{x^k}{k!} A^k=I+ \sum_{k=1}^\inf \frac{x^k}{k!} 3^{k-1}A = I + \frac{1}{3}(1+\sum_{k=1}^\inf \frac{x^k}{k!} 3^{k} -1)A=I + \frac{1}{3}(e^{3x}-1)A$